# How to see list of curl ciphers?

Tags: curl, ssl, https

My understanding is that during ssl negotiation, the client (i.e. curl) sends a list of ciphers to the server, and the server replies with its preferred choice.

How do I see the list of ciphers that curl is sending?

Answer (score 25):

There is a website that offers curl cipher request detection as a service:

```
curl https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check
```

However, it does not accept all ciphers - if one of the ciphers they accept is not on the list that your curl is sending, then you will not be able to get a response at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark). For example, if you set a packet filter of "tcp port 443" and then set the display filter to "ssl", you'll get output like this:

[image: Wireshark screenshot showing Client Hello of TLS]

You can see that the "Client Hello" packet shows cipher suites like `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [1] is a good start, but it glosses over how to actually create a
self-signed certificate, and the answer doesnt work without that part. Further,
the article [2] they link to with instruction on how to create a self-signed
certificate is using OpenSSL, which is good for some purposes, but maybe not
ideal for creating a self-signed certificate, as it makes the process harder
than it needs to be. To that end, I found another tool [3], thats much simpler:

```
generate_cert -host localhost
```

Its just a single file written in Go, with no external dependencies. After you
run the above command, you can then use OpenSSL or similar to start a server:

```
openssl s_server -msg -accept 8080 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
```

Then make a request like this:

```
curl -k https://localhost:8080
```

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667824
2. https://netburner.com/learn/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-for-secure-iot-applications
3. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.17.4/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Comment: Generating a self-signed cert is as "easy" as `openssl req -x509 -subj /CN=example.com -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem`.  For some reason the linked answer was deleted, but is at https://web.archive.org/web/20220518165811/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208412/how-to-see-list-of-curl-ciphers#answer-667824